# Module of finite length $\implies$ finite direct sum of indecomposable modules

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

I'm trying to solve the following question.

> Let $M$ be an $R$-module of finite length (i.e, both Artinian and Noetherian). Prove that it is isomorphic to a finite direct sum of indecomposable submodules.

I was thinking I could induct on the length, though I'm having a difficulty in the induction step.

Base case holds trivially. If for all modules of length $ <n $, the proposition holds, consider a module of length $n$, which has the following decomposition:$$ M \supset M_1 \supset \ldots \supset M_n \supset (0) $$

By the Induction hypotheses, $M_1$ is isomorphic to a finite direct sum of indecomposable modules.
Now, if I show that the following short exact sequence splits, then I'm done.
$$ 0 \rightarrow M_{1} \rightarrow M \rightarrow M/M_1 \rightarrow 0 $$
But I'm unable to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* The size of a decomposition as a sum of nontrivial modules is bounded by the length of the module. Do you see why, and can you proceed from here? The crucial thing is that the length of *any* decomposition series bounds the size of *any other* nontrivial filtration - have you already proved this?

Comment: Oh, by finite length, I meant the module is both an Artinian as well as a Noetherian Module.

Comment: @Karthik: Yes - but I think the example is valid nonetheless?

Comment: Yes, I do apologize.
Not simple, but indecomposable. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ah! That does change matters :)

Comment: @Karthik Do you have any questions?

Comment: No. Thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

If $M$ is indecomposable, you're done. Otherwise, $M=X\oplus Y$, with $X$ and $Y$ both nonzero.

Now prove that the lengths of $X$ and $Y$ are less than the length of $M$.

Hint: build composition series for $X$ and $Y$ and paste them up.